# ReactJS - Click event attached on a list of elements is triggering "click" for all elements in the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im having a set of li elements under ul element (such as shown below), when I click on any li element I want it to attach a class name to it. However, when i click on any on li element, click event for all the li elements are triggered and class gets attached to all li elements.

```
ul
----li onclickEvent 
----li onclickEvent 
----li onclickEvent 
----li onclickEvent 
----li onclickEvent
```

How can i fix this? Is there an example that I can study?

```
var k=0;
var children = function(d,clO){
  var newClassName = "class1";
  if(clO.state.class1){
    var variableClassName = newClassName;
  }else{
    var variableClassName = "";
  }
  var toggle = function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    clO.setState({class1: !clO.state.class1});
    if(clO.state.class1){
      variableClassName = newClassName;
    }else{
      variableClassName = "";
    }
  };

  var span = React.DOM.span({"className":variableClassName, key:"s"+d.s, onClick: toggle },null);
  return [span];
};

var parent = function(d,clO,inv){
  k = k+1;
  var l = [];
  for(var i=0; i<d.length;i++){
    l.push(React.DOM.li({key:"ul_"+k+"li_"+i}, children(d[i], clO)));
  }
  if(inv){
    return React.DOM.ul({key:k, "className":"invisible"}, l);
  }else{
    return React.DOM.ul({key:k}, l);
  }
};

var cl = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {class1: true};
    },
    render:function(){
        var obj = parent(this.props.storage, this);
        return obj;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onClick={this.functionName}`

instead of `onclick={this.functionName()}`